# SignalR cannot call client function when using StructureMap dependency resolver

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, signalr, structuremap

When I include a structuremap dependency resolver in my global.asax for signalR any calls to client functions no longer arrive at the browser although I can see them if in the logging pipeline.

Here's an extract of my global.asax:

```
var container = ObjectFactory.Container;

// Now configure SignalR, MVC, ASP.Net and SharpRepository

GlobalHost.HubPipeline.AddModule(new ErrorHandlingPipelineModule());
GlobalHost.HubPipeline.AddModule(new LoggingPipelineModule());

// TODO: Work out why this breaks the connection between the server and the client.

GlobalHost.DependencyResolver = 
    ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IDependencyResolver>();
RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs();

DependencyResolver.SetResolver(
    new StructureMapDependencyResolver(container));
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = 
    new StructureMapDependencyResolver(container);
RepositoryDependencyResolver.SetDependencyResolver(
    new SharpRepository.Ioc.StructureMap.StructureMapDependencyResolver(container));
```

Here the implementation of the structuremap resolver:

```
public class StructureMapSignalRDependencyResolver 
    : DefaultDependencyResolver
{
    private readonly IContainer _container;

    public StructureMapSignalRDependencyResolver(
        IContainer container)
    {
        if (container == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("container");
        }

        _container = container;
    }

    public override object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        object result = null;

        try
        {
            result = 
                !serviceType.IsAbstract &&
                !serviceType.IsInterface &&
                serviceType.IsClass
                    ? _container.GetInstance(serviceType)
                    : (_container.TryGetInstance(serviceType) 
                        ?? base.GetService(serviceType));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Tracing.Error(
                "[StructureMapSignalRDependencyResolver]",
                 Tracing.SerializeException(ex));
        }

        if (result == null)
        {
            Tracing.Information(
                "[StructureMapSignalRDependencyResolver]",
                "Could retrieve object of type {0}",serviceType.ToString());
        }

        return result;
    }

    public override IEnumerable<object> GetServices(
        Type serviceType)
    {
        IEnumerable<object> result = null;

        try
        {
            result = _container.GetAllInstances(serviceType)
                .Cast<object>().Concat(
                    base.GetServices(serviceType));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Tracing.Error(
                "[StructureMapSignalRDependencyResolver]", 
                Tracing.SerializeException(ex));
        }

        if (result == null)
        {
            Tracing.Information(
                "[StructureMapSignalRDependencyResolver]", 
                "Could retrieve object of type {0}", serviceType.ToString());
        }

        return result;
    }

    public override void Register(Type serviceType, 
        Func<object> activator)
    {
        Tracing.Information(
            "[StructureMapSignalRDependencyResolver]", 
            "Registering object of type {0}", 
            serviceType.ToString());

        base.Register(serviceType, activator);
    }

    public override void Register(Type serviceType, 
        IEnumerable<Func<object>> activators)
    {
        Tracing.Information(
            "[StructureMapSignalRDependencyResolver]", 
            "Registering object of type {0}", 
            serviceType.ToString());

        base.Register(serviceType, activators);
    }
}
```

Here is the implementation of StructureMap Registry (there are many more which include the application assemblies).

```
[RegistryOrder(Order = 6)]
public class SignalRRegistry : Registry
{
    public SignalRRegistry()
    {
        For<IDependencyResolver>().Singleton()
            .Use<StructureMapSignalRDependencyResolver>();
        For<IHubConnectionContext>().Singleton()
            .Use(GlobalHost.ConnectionManager
                .GetHubContext<BOSSHub>().Clients);     
    }

    //public void Configure()
    //{
    //    GlobalHost.DependencyResolver = 
    //        ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IDependencyResolver>();
    //    RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs();
    //}
}
```

I've rolled back the Hub class so that it no longer has an dependencies; the output from WhatDoIHave seems to have some entries for Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR but without any concrete relationships.

I wondering if I missed a step in my registry ? I get no exceptions anywhere; it just stops working, if I comment out the GlobalHost.DependencyResolver line from global.asax all is well.

I hope someone could share with me a DI implementation for signalR that is working for them.

Many Thanks

UPDATE: Thanks for sorting out the bad formatting for me - appreciate that.

UPDATE: I've put together a small test project which shows the issue. I was surprised if I'm honest I was able to reproduce it as the application that I'm working on it pretty big and complex with lot's of StructureMap stuff going on. I've uploaded into GitHub : https://github.com/johnk27stars/SignalRTest.git - Thanks to anyone who could spare a minute to take a look.

Comment: Could you share a minimum project in a zip file or a git repository?

Comment: UPDATE: I've now included the singular source code into my solution to see if I can gain anymore insight. What I've found is that when I'm using the DI container signalR seems to lose it's topics collection somewhere in the pipeline and although the message still looks good it doesn't build out any subscribers.

Comment: UPDATE: I've uploaded into GitHub : https://github.com/johnk27stars/SignalRTest.git - Thanks to anyone who could spare a minute to take a look.

Comment: Maybe it's your dependency resolver impl. Isn't there one for your container already?

Comment: Yep sure is - I've tried the nugget package version (even though it references signalR 0.4) and I've also copied a couple of variations from over stackoverflow which I've found too - all with the same result.

Answer (score 0):

After some honest advice from Jeremy Miller we switched to AutoFac and it working fine.